# Fixtures to popualte ManyToOne field from csv data

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

The entity `category` has a ManyToOne relation with `type` so each category has one type, and each type can relate to many categories.

I loaded the `type` form a csv as follows :

```
$types = fopen(__DIR__.'/types.csv','r');        
while (!feof($types)){

        $line = fgetcsv($types);
        $data = str_getcsv($line[0],';');
        $t[$i] = new Type();
        $t[$i]->setIdType($data[0]);
        $t[$i]->setDescription($data[1]);

        $manager->persist($t[$i]);
        $manager->flush();
        $i++;
    }

    fclose($agregatnational);
```

Now I have to load the `categories` the same way : reading from a csv and inserting the values to a relation field without breaking the relation (read the id from the csv then search for the `type` object that has this id, map that object to the current `category`).

Keep in mind that I can't generate random id's.
Can someone help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your classes look like, but it seem like you save the original Id of the type in a field called idType. If that's the case you can use ist to get the persisted entity:

```
$categories = fopen(__DIR__.'/categories.csv','r');        
while (!feof($categories)){

    $line = fgetcsv($categories);
    $data = str_getcsv($line[0],';');

    $type = $manager->getRepository('Type::class')->findOneBy(['idType' => data[1]);

    $new = new Category();
    $new->setType($type);
    $new->setName($data[0);

    $manager->persist($new);
    $manager->flush();
    $i++;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you ! the `$manager->getRepository('')->findOneBy` is the part I was missing.